# How to create a socket on a 2nd NIC card?

Tags: qt, sockets, nic

I'm trying to create a server on a secondary network in our office which is connected to a 2nd NIC card in my PC.  I haven't had any luck finding a solution on the internet.

Is there a way to direct Qt to use that NIC card?

In my project, here's the code that starts the server.  If `mIP` is on the first NIC card, this code works, if on the second NIC card, the `listen()` errors out.

```
void MyServer::run()
{
    QHostAddress serverAddr( mIP );
    QTcpServer server;

    mUi->lineEdit_ServerConnectionStatus->setText("Running");

    if (server.listen(serverAddr, mPort))
    {
        ...
```

Thanks,
Joe B.

Comment: How does it "error out"? Please print out the `errorString` after `listen` returns false. Also provide a dump from `QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces`. IIRC `qDebug()` can do the latter as well.

Comment: Being new to Qt, I'm still learning all of the tools at my disposal.  thanks for the tip about ::allInterfaces.  I actually ended up using allAddresses b/c that outputs the info as an IP address...and when I ran the code I discovered I had a typo in my IP address...doh!  It now creates the socket on the 2nd NIC card no differently than it did for the other NIC card.  Thanks again!!!